# Creating three children and connecting pipes between them

Tags: linux, pipe, fork, parent-child, parent

I am in need of some help of understanding how to create one parent and three children and connecting pipes between the childrens.

My task is to get the first child to run `ls -l /bin/??` and send it to the second child that will run `grep rwxr-xr-x` and send that to the third child that will run `sort`.

It wil look like this if typed in to bash:
`ls -l /bin/?? | grep rwxr-xr-x | sort`

My code right now:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#inlcude <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

int main()
{
  int fds[2], i;
  pid_t pid;
  pipe(fds);

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
     pid = fork();
     if(pid == (pid_t) 0)
        if(i == 0)
        {
           /* First child */
        }
     else if(i == 1)
     {
        /* second child */
     }
     else if(i == 2)
     {
        /* Third child */
     }
     break;
  else 
  {
      /* This is the parent */
  }
 }
}
```

The problem is that i don't really know if this is the correct way of doing it. 
Please avoid telling me to do this with threads as I am trying to learn pipes and communication between processes.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a fork() in a loop. Every fork() will result in two processes. So total you are creating 8 processes. Need to take that fork() call out of the loop.
This is how fork works,

```
     fork() [Process 1]
                /\
               /  \
[Process 1]fork() fork()[Process 2]
                    /\
                   /  \
    [Process 2]fork() fork()[Process 3]
```

To achieve what you aspire try following code,

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid[3];

    pid[0] = fork();

    if( pid[0] == 0)
    {
        /* First Process */
        pid[1] = fork();
        if(pid[1] == 0)
        {
            /* First Process Continued. */
        }
        else
        {
            /* Second Process */
        }
     }
     else
     {
         /* 3rd Process */
     }
return 0;
}
```